# Putting a Different bumper on my car

Tags: ford, bumper

Okay so i have a ford fiesta zetec mk6 1.4 orange and just wanted to know if I could put a ford fiesta s bumper on my car because the zetec s bumper looks a bit more sporty then mine and mine has a few scratches and dents but don't want to buy the bumper and it not fit and I don't mind if its another colour I will get it sprayed the same once its on.

Thanks

This is my car

[image: This is my car]

And wanted a bumper like this 
http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Ford-Fiesta-Mk6-Mk7-2005-2008-Zetec-S-Front-Bumper-Centre-Grill-Surround-Kit-/361302415065?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_3&hash=item541f4d56d9

Answer (score 2):

The Mk6 Fiesta was subject to a facelift in 2005 when Ford changed a number of things about the car including the headlights and grill along with the front bumper.

Apparently facelift parts can be fitted on a pre-facelift car but there is a rivet to drill out and replace so make so you have a rivet gun to hand if you do this conversion.  So, in summary, if you want this bumper to fit straight on your car you may need to change the headlights and grill for those from a 2005-2008 Fiesta which can presumably be had from a breakers yard if you find a car that's suffered rear end damage.

Answer (score 0):

Need to check size but nearly any bumper can be made to fit if u know how to use fiber glass .
If not u can check size spec on manufacturer website l.

Comment: While your answer may be accurate ... how would one go about doing anything you've said here? Can you provide what the person would actually do to make it happen? As it stands, your answer provides affirmation of the ability, but really doesn't provide an answer to the question at large. Please flesh your answer out, or others will most likely to close it as low quality.